# Attempting complete exercise 3 of Scraping Club, however, I seem only to be able to retrieve the first item; how can this be fixed?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape this website page: https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1

This page is meant to resemble an online clothing store. The main issue that I've encountered is that the HTML tags I see when I inspect the HTML are not the same as the ones written in the solutions I've seen online.

I would like to print all clothing items on this page.

Here is what I have written currently. I've attempted to search for solutions in a variety of websites, however, it seems as though quite a few HTML tags have been updated since the solutions I found were written, making them irrelevant. The code retrieves the HTML for multiple items, however in the for loop, it only prints out the first item.

I was expecting the code to print out the count, the corresponding item price, and the corresponding item name, however it only retrieved the first item.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url) #this fetches the HTML code of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-3') #it's fetched multiple items
#print(items)
count = 1
for i in items:
    item_name = i.find('h4').text.strip()
    item_price = i.find('h5').text.strip()
    print('%s ) Price: %s, Item Name: %s' % (count, item_price, item_name))
    count += 1
    #print(i)
```

Comment: What debugging did you try? Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). `items` is a list containing a single `div` element. There are multiple `h4` and `h5` elements in this `div`, but you use `.find` which only gets you the first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can retrieve names, prices + using `enumerate()` to get count of items:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

for i, label in enumerate(soup.select("div:has(>h4)"), 1):
    name, price = label.h4.text.strip(), label.h5.text.strip()
    print(f"{i:^5} {name:<40} {price:<10}")
```

Prints:

```
  1   Short Dress                              $24.99    
  2   Patterned Slacks                         $29.99    
  3   Short Chiffon Dress                      $49.99    
  4   Off-the-shoulder Dress                   $59.99    
  5   V-neck Top                               $24.99    
  6   Short Chiffon Dress                      $49.99    
  7   V-neck Top                               $24.99    
  8   V-neck Top                               $24.99    
  9   Short Lace Dress                         $59.99    
 10   Fitted Dress                             $34.99
```